# Innosetup #define from function in pascal [code] section

Tags: inno-setup

I have a setup using Inno Setup where I would like to have an entire section installed only if a certain condition is met.  The condition is calculated in `[Code]` section using a Pascal script.

It would be run-time / dynamic, based on a (hardware) condition in the computer to install to.

What I am after is something like this:  (pseudo code, used to illustrate my ideas). For my setup it's indifferent what type the defined variable has, as long as it can be variable.

```ini
; --- 
; --- initial section
; 
#define testvarvalue {mytestfunction()}

[files]
; --- 
; --- only do this section if certain condition is met
#if testvarvalue == "A"
   ; -- do something here
#endif 


; --- 
; --- functions
[code]
function mytestfunction: string;
   begin
     result:= 'A';
   end;
```

Comment: It would be run-time / dynamic, based on a (hardware) condition in the computer to install to. Thank you for the hints.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, thank you, I know the flags but it's not that simple. So it has be a function based on code. If I can't do what I imagine possible, I will use the `Check: somefunction` .

Comment: What's wrong with using `Check:`?